# NgRx effect not being called

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I recently configured NgRx in one of my projects and implemented action, reducers, and effects for a specific model called `OrderModel`.

But when I dispatch an action that I configured an effect to be run on that, the effect, simply does not run.

Anyone has an idea why?

Here is my `OrderModel`:

```
export interface OrderModel {
  orderNumber?: number;
  destination?: LatLngLiteral;
  source?: LatLngLiteral;
  accepted?: boolean;
  sourceAddressText?: string;
  destinationAddressText?: string;
}
```

Here are the actions:

```
export const addRawOrder = createAction('[Order] Add new orders', props<{orders: OrderModel[]}>());
export const addOrder = createAction('[Order] Add new orders', props<{orders: OrderModel[]}>());
export const setSelectedOrder = createAction('[Order] Set selected order', props<{order: OrderModel}>());
export const setSelectedOrderAccepted = createAction('[Order] Set selected order accepted', props<{order: OrderModel}>());
```

Here are the reducer codes:

```
import {addOrder, addRawOrder, setSelectedOrder, setSelectedOrderAccepted} from "./order-actions";

export interface OrderState {
  orders: OrderModel[];
  selectedOrder: OrderModel | null;
}


const initialState: OrderState = {orders: [], selectedOrder: null};

export const orderReducers = createReducer(initialState,
  on(addRawOrder, (state, {orders}) => ({...state})),
  on(addOrder, (state, {orders}) => ({...state, orders: [...state.orders, ...orders]})),
  on(setSelectedOrder, (state, {order}) => ({...state, selectedOrder: order})),
  on(setSelectedOrderAccepted, (state, {order}) => ({...state, selectedOrder: {...order, accepted: true}}))
);
```

Here is the Effect code:

```
@Injectable()
export class OrderEffects {

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private neshanService: NeshanService) {
  }

  getPosts$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(addRawOrder),
      switchMap((action) => {
        return this.neshanService.reverseGeocodingSourceDestinationOder(action.orders);
      }),
      map(orders => addOrder({orders: orders}))
    )
  )
}
```

Here is the config in the  imports section of the `app.module.ts`:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({orders: orderReducers}),
EffectsModule.forRoot([OrderEffects]),
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `tap(console.log)` or peeking into storeDevtools to see if the effect works at all for that action? There is on unusual thing I noticed, but I don't think it would be the culprit. This line `map(orders => addOrder({orders: orders}))` would typically be hooked up to `pipe` of the inner observable (after service call, within `switchMap`)

Comment: Yeah, I tried using tap and console log, but nothing gets logged to the console.

Comment: One concern is that `addRawOrder` and `addOrder` have the same action type string. Even if this is not the cause of the issue it's not a redux pattern - I cannot tell the action's origin just by looking at the type. Please take debugging steps to establish: is the action dispatched (chrome storeDevtools) and which one with what state, is `OrderEffects` registered (`console.log` in constructor), does the `reverseGeocodingSourceDestinationOder` return what you expect.

Comment: At what point did you tap? If you tap before "ofType" you may check if you have access to action stream. If its not working odds are that the issue is with imports, even though from here it seems fine.

Comment: I have tapped after "ofType", I check to tap before it to see what happens

Comment: The code snippet seems fine to me. Do you have a reproduction? Also, how are you dispatching the action? Do you see it in the Redux DevTools?

Comment: The duplication of type mentioned by Andrew Allen sounds like something I would like to check.

Answer (score 0):

The action `addRawOrder` is handled in both of the reducer and the effect. NGRX start handling the action by the reducer then the effect in case no reducer interested of the action.
The solution is to create a different action for the effect then `addRawOrder`.